# WinUI3 DataGrid how to set row color In application resources Instead of in the data grid

Tags: xaml, user-interface, winui-3

I want to move color overrides for DataGrid resources to Application resources so I don't have to set them for every DataGrid in my application. The colors don't get applied when I move them from DataGrid resources to Application resources. What am I doing wrong?

[Resources defined in DataGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc6Rr.png)

[Resource defined in Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wHK7.png)

Setting row color like this in resource does not change the row color for the data grid

```xml
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <ui:Color x:Key="DataGridRowHoveredBackgroundColor">Green</ui:Color>
                    <ui:Color x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedHoveredBackgroundColor">Green</ui:Color>
                    <ui:Color x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedHoveredUnfocusedBackgroundColor">Green</ui:Color>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Setting row color like this in the data grid resources does work

```xml
<controls:DataGrid.Resources>
    <ui:Color x:Key="DataGridRowHoveredBackgroundColor">Green</ui:Color>
    <ui:Color x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedHoveredBackgroundColor">Green</ui:Color>
    <ui:Color x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedHoveredUnfocusedBackgroundColor">Green</ui:Color>           
</controls:DataGrid.Resources>
```

```
xmlns:ui="using:Windows.UI"
xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls"
```

Comment: I reproduced and it also doesn't work with defining such [`StaticResources`](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3ACommunityToolkit%2FWindowsCommunityToolkit%20DataGridRowSelectedHoveredBackgroundColor&type=code) in `App.xaml`.

Answer (score 0):

Resources defined in our application resources cannot overwrite the resources in `DataGrid.xaml`. See [Lookup behavior for XAML resource references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-resource-dictionary#lookup-behavior-for-xaml-resource-references) for more information.
But [Every FrameworkElement can have a ResourceDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-resource-dictionary#every-frameworkelement-can-have-a-resourcedictionary). You can define these resources in parent element's dictionaries.
I have tested it working.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Color x:Key="DataGridRowHoveredBackgroundColor">Green</Color>
            <Color x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedHoveredBackgroundColor">Green</Color>
            <Color x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedHoveredUnfocusedBackgroundColor">Green</Color>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        
        <YANG:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" 
    Height="600" Margin="12"
    AutoGenerateColumns="True"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind Customers}" >
            <!--<YANG:DataGrid.Resources>
                <Color x:Key="DataGridRowHoveredBackgroundColor">Green</Color>
                <Color x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedHoveredBackgroundColor">Green</Color>
                <Color x:Key="DataGridRowSelectedHoveredUnfocusedBackgroundColor">Green</Color>
            </YANG:DataGrid.Resources>-->
        </YANG:DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
```

Also see the similar thread https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/3946

Update:

> Strange it doesn't work for DataGrid but does work for other controls
> like ComboBox and Buttons.

As we can see in the generated `App.xaml`, the `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls` resources are merged.
According to [Merged dictionary behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/systems/xaml-resources-merged-dictionaries?view=netdesktop-7.0#merged-dictionary-behavior):

> Resources in a merged dictionary occupy a location in the resource
> lookup scope that's just after the scope of the main resource
> dictionary they are merged into. Although a resource key must be
> unique within any individual dictionary, a key can exist multiple
> times in a set of merged dictionaries. In this case, the resource
> that's returned will come from the last dictionary found sequentially
> in the MergedDictionaries collection. If the MergedDictionaries
> collection was defined in XAML, then the order of the merged
> dictionaries in the collection is the order of the elements as
> provided in the markup. If a key is defined in the primary dictionary
> and also in a dictionary that was merged, then the resource that's
> returned will come from the primary dictionary. These scoping rules
> apply equally for both static resource references and dynamic resource
> references.

```
<!-- Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation and Contributors. -->
<!-- Licensed under the MIT License. -->

<Application
    x:Class="App2CSharp.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2CSharp">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!--<Color x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver">Green</Color> work-->
            <!--<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="Green"></SolidColorBrush>
            <StaticResource x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" ResourceKey="MyBrush"/> work-->

            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Color x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver">Green</Color><!--doesn't work-->
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
                <!-- Other merged dictionaries here -->
                <!--<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="Green"></SolidColorBrush>
                <StaticResource x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" ResourceKey="MyBrush"/> work-->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Other app resources here -->
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Strange it doesn't work for DataGrid but does work for other controls like ComboBox and Buttons. This is a pain point for using XAML and WinUI3 because I haven't found a cleaner solution to changing colours that are not a template resource besides overriding. Ideally it would be nice to be able to set these resources in style so I don't have to set them globally or per element.

Comment: @eric-v `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls` resources are merged resources which stay after the scope of the main resource dictionary they are merged into. For style, try to [Use based-on styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-styles#use-based-on-styles).